# How do I build the root module of a gradle project?

Tags: gradle, clojure, build.gradle

I have created a gradle project with sub-modules:
service
--clojure
--api

I don't have any source files in the root directory, and I don't need it to be build into a jar as it is just a root directory for a repository.

If I was using maven I would have set packaging to pom for the root module:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

However, I don't know how to set similar configuration in gradle.

I know there is no harm in having the root module built, but I would like to somehow configure which modules are built into archives and which are not.

Is there someway to instruct gradle to build archives for the sub-module, only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to update that we accidentally stumbled upon the way to do that.

Gradle has directives for "allprojects" and "subprojects", we removed "allprojects" from build.gradle of the root directory and now only the sub-modules are built.